# Cox model appropriate for my time to event problem?

Tags: cox-model, count-data, censoring

I am trying to estimate the factors associated with delay in implementation of a policy. 
I am analyzing the delay, measured by number of days, it took an entity to implement one of three policies, after they detected a problem. Therefore, in my dataset I observe entities after they have detected a problem. Many would not have implemented a policy in the time period observed (censored data). Also, if we were to to observe some companies for an infinite time, it is possible that they may not implement the policy. Also the later you detect the problem, the more likely you are to have a shorter delay, because you know that other companies have had the same problem, and you may have even implemented the policy before others have detected the problem. This almost makes it seem that the exposure period should be the time since the first problem was detected, which would make exposure the same for everyone.

The cox model I am using in stata gives me the probability of a company implementing a policy given a vector of predictor variables. While I know if a company implements a policy they have a shorter delay, I am more interested the exact association between predictor variables and delay in number of implementation. For example, I would like to see being in region X1 is associated with a Y day increase in delay in policy. What would be the most appropriate model for my problem? Should I ignore companies that did not implement the policy in this analysis? Thanks in advance!